Unable to pickup $(this).parent() value in Chrome
I have a series of generated buttons inside a div called scrollArea.
                <h3 id="searchLabel">Select User(s)</h3>
                <div class="scrollArea" id="resultsPane" name="resultsPane" >
                </div>

This would appear inside the Div:
<div value=""" & ajaxRS("userid") & """ alt=""" & ajaxRS("fullname") & """>
<span class=""buttonlink minibutton"">Select</span>
<b>" & ajaxRS("fullname") & "</b><br/>
Employer: " & ajaxRS("employer") & ",&nbsp;Location: " & ajaxRS("location") & "</div>

For the record, I am horrible at Javascript and jQuery.The following jQuery looks for the click event of the buttonlink inside the scrollArea. The object values holds the employee number. This works great in Internet Explorer, but Chrome yields an empty object. Being that "live" is depreciated, i have tried "on", but have not been successful. I tried doing this in Javascript as well, but it never gets the object value either. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
                $(".scrollArea .buttonlink").live("click", function () {
        objClicked = $(this).parent();
        $("#pendAssignments").append($(objClicked).attr("alt") + "  "); objClicked.hide();
        $("#relToSave").append(
  "<input name=\"usersToAssign\" value=\"" + $(objClicked).val() + "\">"  
        );
        alertSuccess();
        <% if instancing = "S" or sMode = "EDIT" then %>
        $(".scrollArea .buttonlink").hide(); 
        $("#loadAllUsers").hide();
        $(".scrollArea").fadeTo("fast", 0.35);
        <% end if %>
        <% if aid > 30000 then %>
        $("#bNotify").show();
        <% end if %>
    });


Off topic: .live was deprecated in jquery 1.7, which was released in 2011!  Probably time to upgrade.

I'm such an idiot.... The answer was right in front of me.
    $(objClicked).val()

should be:
    $(objClicked).attr("value")

I noticed that it was populating names on the page, but not displaying the employee number. Then I noticed this:
    $(objClicked).attr("alt")

I wasnt picking up the attribute of the button "value". Here is the corrected code.
                $(".scrollArea .buttonlink").live("click", function () {
        objClicked = $(this).parent();
        $("#pendAssignments").append($(objClicked).attr("alt") + "  "); objClicked.hide();
        $("#relToSave").append(
  "<input name=\"usersToAssign\" value=\"" + $(objClicked).attr("value") + "\">"  
        );
        alertSuccess();
        <% if instancing = "S" or sMode = "EDIT" then %>
        $(".scrollArea .buttonlink").hide(); 
        $("#loadAllUsers").hide();
        $(".scrollArea").fadeTo("fast", 0.35);
        <% end if %>
        <% if aid > 30000 then %>
        $("#bNotify").show();
        <% end if %>
    });

